# Изменение пути в git config

Tags: git, git-config

Перенёс все программы в одну папку, но в git config путь прописан без этой папки и ничего не работает. Попытался сам переделать путь к vs code, и теперь у меня их 2 (один нужно удалить)
Так же нужно изменить путь для директории с git

```
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=F:/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt /*прописать сюда правильный путь*/
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
credential.helper=manager-core
credential.https://dev.azure.com.usehttppath=true
init.defaultbranch=main
core.editor=F:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code  
core.editor='F:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code' /*удалить эту строку*/
```

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `git config --add core.editor 'F:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code'`

Comment: Nyuhnyash "git config --add" не будет работать, вместо "add" насколько я понял пишут global/list (то где именно в конфиге поменять) (либо же ничего не пишут,когда хотят локально изменить) к примеру когда ты добавляешь емаил ты пишешь git config --global user.email "*mail*"

Comment: Почему нельзя просто файл открыть и отредактировать как надо?